# T-SQL Join two tables where the join condition is dependant on values in both tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which combines data from two tables.

Policy table

```
PolicyID    PolicyNumber    PolicyStartDate
48  FCO100009   2015-06-01 00:00:00.000
49  FCO100009   2016-06-01 00:00:00.000
```

Claim Table

```
ClaimID ClaimReference  PolicyNumber    IncidentDatetime    NotificationDatetime    Version
30  287 FCO100009   2015-11-06 00:00:00.000 2015-11-27 00:00:00.000 4. Claim - Incident Date
223 259 FCO100009   2015-11-03 00:00:00.000 2015-11-20 00:00:00.000 4. Claim - Incident Date
1367    988 FCO100009   2016-04-15 00:00:00.000 2016-04-21 00:00:00.000 4. Claim - Incident Date
1561    1859    FCO100009   2016-09-14 00:00:00.000 2016-09-19 00:00:00.000 4. Claim - Incident Date
1741    443275  FCO100009   2016-05-11 00:00:00.000 2016-05-12 00:00:00.000 4. Claim - Incident Date
1742    991 FCO100009   2016-04-20 00:00:00.000 2016-04-21 00:00:00.000 4. Claim - Incident Date
2038    287 FCO100009   2015-11-06 00:00:00.000 2015-11-27 00:00:00.000 5. Claim - Notification Date
3744    259 FCO100009   2015-11-03 00:00:00.000 2015-11-20 00:00:00.000 5. Claim - Notification Date
3745    991 FCO100009   2016-04-20 00:00:00.000 2016-04-21 00:00:00.000 5. Claim - Notification Date
4502    1859    FCO100009   2016-09-14 00:00:00.000 2016-09-19 00:00:00.000 5. Claim - Notification Date
4639    988 FCO100009   2016-04-15 00:00:00.000 2016-04-21 00:00:00.000 5. Claim - Notification Date
6600    443275  FCO100009   2016-05-11 00:00:00.000 2016-05-12 00:00:00.000 5. Claim - Notification Date
```

There are 2 records for the Policy with different Policy Start Dates and a 2 versions of each claim record where the Version field is either Claim Incident Date or Claim Notification Date.

What I am attempting to accomplish is joining the two tables on PolicyNumber and then setting the PolicyStartDate value in the results to be the maximum value from Policy.PolicyStartDate where the PolicyStartDate is less than the NotificationDate when Version = NotificationDate OR PolicyStartDate is less than the Incident Date when Version = IncidentDate.

Please note that this is using financial NOT Calendar years and in this case the year of account runs from April to March.

Here is my current query which doesn't produce the correct answer:

```
SELECT  cds.ClaimID,
        cds.ClaimReference,
        p.policyID,
        p.PolicyStartDate,
        cds.IncidentDatetime,
        cds.NotificationDatetime, 
        cds.[Version]
FROM    dbo.ClaimDataStaging cds
        INNER JOIN dbo.[Policy] p
            ON p.PolicyNumber = cds.PolicyNumber
                AND p.PolicyStartDate < CASE WHEN cds.[Version] = '4. Claim - Incident Date' THEN cds.IncidentDatetime
                                        WHEN cds.[Version] = '5. Claim - Notification Date' THEN cds.NotificationDatetime END
WHERE   cds.PolicyNumber = 'FCO100009'
ORDER BY cds.[Version], cds.ClaimReference;         
GO
```

Any help or advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions received, I was able to adjust my query to provide the required result. Here is my final code for reference:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        cds.ClaimID,
        MAX(p.PolicyID) OVER (PARTITION BY cds.PolicyNumber) AS PolicyID,
        MAX(p.PolicyStartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY cds.PolicyNumber) AS 
        PolicyStartDate, cds.ClaimKey, cds.ClaimReference, cds.ClaimStatus, 
        cds.IncidentDatetime, cds.NotificationDatetime, cds.UW_Date, 
        cds.IncidentType, cds.IncidentDescription, cds.OwnDamagePaid,
        cds.OwnDamageReserve, cds.OwnDamageIncurred, cds.TPDamagePaid, 
        cds.TPDamageReserve, cds.TPDamageIncurred,
        cds.BodilyInjuryPaid, cds.BodilyInjuryReserve, 
        cds.BodilyInjuryIncurred, cds.TotalPaid, cds.TotalReserve,
        cds.EstimatedRecovery, cds.ActualRecovery, cds.TotalIncurred, cds.TotalIncurredBand, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), 'Current Period') AS TimeView, 1 AS ClaimCount, CONVERT(VARCHAR(48), [Version]) AS [Version]       
FROM    dbo.ClaimDataStaging cds
        INNER JOIN dbo.UW_Calendar u
            ON u.UW_Date = cds.UW_Date
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Policy] p
        ON p.PolicyNumber = cds.PolicyNumber
            AND p.PolicyStartDate <=    CASE
                                            WHEN cds.[Version] = '4. Claim - Incident Date' THEN cds.IncidentDatetime
                                            WHEN cds.[Version] = '5. Claim - Notification Date' THEN cds.NotificationDatetime
                                        END;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like the query below.  It will give you the max policy number based on the filter you had for the dates.

```
SELECT  cds.ClaimID,
        cds.ClaimReference,
        p.policyID,
        p.PolicyStartDate,
        cds.IncidentDatetime,
        cds.NotificationDatetime, 
        cds.[Version]
FROM    dbo.ClaimDataStaging cds
    CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT PolicyStartDate = MAX(fp.PolicyStartDate)
            FROM dbo.[Policy] fp
            WHERE fp.PolicyNumber = cds.PolicyNumber
            AND ((fp.PolicyStartDate < cds.IncidentDatetime AND cds.[Version] = '4. Claim - Incident Date')
                OR (fp.PolicyStartDate < cds.NotificationDatetime AND cds.[Version] = '5. Claim - Notification Date')) sp
    INNER JOIN dbo.[Policy] p ON p.PolicyNumber = cds.PolicyNumber AND p.PolicyStartDate = sp.PolicyStartDate
WHERE   cds.PolicyNumber = 'FCO100009'
ORDER BY cds.[Version], cds.ClaimReference;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested solution. Unfortunately, this does not return the desired results. The expected return would be: PolicyStartDate = 2015-06-01 for the first two rows (Claim Refs 259 & 287) and 2016-06-01 for the others which places them into the correct financial year which runs from April to March.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question and your problem (duplicates caused by condition on date < date which catches former policy too), you can try this query too.
It use LEAD() function to calculate a sort of Enddate (I used IS NULL to to catch last policy, but you can change it adapting to your needs).

I moved the CASE in an inner query to avoid repeating of it in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT  cds.ClaimID,
        cds.ClaimReference,
        p.policyID,
        p.PolicyStartDate,
        cds.IncidentDatetime,
        cds.NotificationDatetime, 
        cds.[Version]
FROM    (SELECT ClaimID, ClaimReference, IncidentDatetime,NotificationDatetime,[Version], PolicyNumber
        , CASE WHEN [Version] = '4. Claim - Incident Date' THEN IncidentDatetime
               WHEN [Version] = '5. Claim - Notification Date' THEN NotificationDatetime END AS CheckDate
         FROM dbo.ClaimDataStaging) cds
INNER JOIN (SELECT policyID, PolicyNumber, PolicyStartDate
            , LEAD(PolicyStartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY PolicyStartDate) AS PolicyEndDate FROM dbo.Policy ) p
            ON p.PolicyNumber = cds.PolicyNumber
            AND p.PolicyStartDate <  CheckDate 
            AND (p.PolicyEndDate IS NULL OR p.PolicyEndDate>=CheckDate)
WHERE   cds.PolicyNumber = 'FCO100009'
ORDER BY cds.[Version], cds.ClaimReference;
```

Output:

```
+---------+----------------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| ClaimID | ClaimReference | policyID |     PolicyStartDate     |    IncidentDatetime     |  NotificationDatetime   |           Version            |
+---------+----------------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+
|     223 |            259 |       48 | 2015-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2015-11-03 00:00:00.000 | 2015-11-20 00:00:00.000 | 4. Claim - Incident Date     |
|      30 |            287 |       48 | 2015-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2015-11-06 00:00:00.000 | 2015-11-27 00:00:00.000 | 4. Claim - Incident Date     |
|    1367 |            988 |       48 | 2015-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-04-15 00:00:00.000 | 2016-04-21 00:00:00.000 | 4. Claim - Incident Date     |
|    1742 |            991 |       48 | 2015-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 2016-04-21 00:00:00.000 | 4. Claim - Incident Date     |
|    1561 |           1859 |       49 | 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-09-14 00:00:00.000 | 2016-09-19 00:00:00.000 | 4. Claim - Incident Date     |
|    1741 |         443275 |       48 | 2015-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-05-11 00:00:00.000 | 2016-05-12 00:00:00.000 | 4. Claim - Incident Date     |
|    3744 |            259 |       48 | 2015-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2015-11-03 00:00:00.000 | 2015-11-20 00:00:00.000 | 5. Claim - Notification Date |
|    2038 |            287 |       48 | 2015-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2015-11-06 00:00:00.000 | 2015-11-27 00:00:00.000 | 5. Claim - Notification Date |
|    4639 |            988 |       48 | 2015-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-04-15 00:00:00.000 | 2016-04-21 00:00:00.000 | 5. Claim - Notification Date |
|    3745 |            991 |       48 | 2015-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 2016-04-21 00:00:00.000 | 5. Claim - Notification Date |
|    4502 |           1859 |       49 | 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-09-14 00:00:00.000 | 2016-09-19 00:00:00.000 | 5. Claim - Notification Date |
|    6600 |         443275 |       48 | 2015-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-05-11 00:00:00.000 | 2016-05-12 00:00:00.000 | 5. Claim - Notification Date |
+---------+----------------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks you for the suggested solution. Unfortunately, this does not return the desired results. the expected return would be:

2015-06-01 for the first two rows (Claim Refs 259 & 287) and 2016-06-01 for the others.

Comment: If you post expected result in a table like mine, I could try to update my query.